# How to use $cond in MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use $cond in Redash to transform a true/false/null to a meaningful value for a report. When I perform the query I only ever get the false case.

This is my query below. I have included the "isSuggestedProgram" in the projection just so I can verify the values for now.

All results show "Custom" as the result regardless of the value of isSuggestedProgram. What is wrong with the way I am doing the $cond?

```
{
    "collection": "Program",
    "aggregate": [
        {
            "$project": {
                "isSuggestedProgram": "$isSuggestedProgram",
                "suggested": {
                    "$cond": {
                        "if": {
                            "$eq": [
                                "$isSuggestedProgram", "true"
                            ]
                        },
                        "then": "Suggested",
                        "else": "Custom"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Becuase you supplied the "string" as `"true"` rather than boolean `true`. Since it's actually a boolean already then you can also write as `"if": "$isSuggestedProgram"` as `true/false` values will determine the branching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stringify your Boolean. What you intend is probably this:

```
"$isSuggestedProgram", true
```

Comment: Oh common. Correcting typo's is not an answer. We have a close reason for it.

Comment: I do not mind if it is closed or deleted. But I think that answering is more transparent than commenting. Cheers.